# Question related to super-modular functions

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, convex-analysis, special-functions

I have two functions $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$ and $g:{\mathbb{R}^k}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$, where $k$ is some finite natural number, $f$ is convex, increasing function and $g$ is the $L_1$ norm.

I also know that $f \circ g$ is a super-modular function. The space we are working on is a Euclidean space.

My questions are,

Is there such an $f$ ? If yes, some examples for the same is appreciated.

In addition to $f$ being convex and increasing, what more is required so that $f \circ g$ is a super-modular function?

My try:
[Convexity and supermodularity](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiX6c6Yo6vUAhULO48KHSmXAk0QFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9780387221991-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-128403-p36983051&usg=AFQjCNEGNGCuxJ1FidooC3271xdHRY1lvw) article suggests that super-modular and convex are somewhat equivalent.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First, we remark $g(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^k x_i$, since $x_i \ge 0$.

Supermodularity of $f \circ g$ requires
$$f\left( \sum_{i=1}^k x_i \right) + f\left( \sum_{i=1}^k y_i \right) \le f\left( \sum_{i=1}^k \min(x_i,y_i)\right) + f\left(\sum_{i=1}^k \max(x_i,y_i)\right)$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb R_+^k$.
Hence, it is sufficient to have
$$f\left( a \right) + f\left( b \right) \le f\left( c \right) + f\left(d \right)$$
for all $c \le a,b \le d$ with $a + b = c + d$.
This easily follows from the convexity of $f$.

Comment: Thanks. To conclude, so convexity of $f$ suffices for $f \circ g$ to be supermodular.

Comment: Yes, convexity is sufficient. However, I believe that convexity is not necessary. If I get it correctly, supermodularity of $f \circ g$ is trivially satisfied in case $k = 1$.